# mule : Scatter and Gather: How to aggregate scatter gather result with original payload?

Tags: mule

I have scatter gather component which calls multiple services and aggregates the result as list of maps. I would like to know is there any way to merge the original payload ( payload which is an input to Scatter Gather) with this result?

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have a map(Key value pair) given as input to scatter-gather flow.And Scatter-gather in turn gives out list of Map.Then you can follow below steps

1. Store the "input" to scatter-gather into a flowVar/SessionVar depending on your need.
2. Once you are out of scatter-gather flow,add Set Payload transformer.
3. In "Set Payload" transformer add [payload.addAll(flowVars['flowVar_Name_which_you_saved_earlier']) as value.

Comment: Using a Set Payload with `#[payload.addAll(...)]` will set the payload as boolean. You should use `#[payload.addAll(...); payload]` instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way is to use "set payload" inside scatter-gather and set the value of the input payload from flowVar. In this case Dataweave "flatten payload" is enough at the end- which is going to be used anyway.